# Send .wav file from SD card to NodeMCU via serial port

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, nodemcu

I was able to send a text file in the SD card to NodeMCU using the serial port of an Arduino Mega using this code:

```cpp
if (readSerial1 == "Okay I'm ready") {
  myFile = sdf.open("uid.txt", FILE_READ);
  if (myFile) {
    while (myFile.available()) {
      char toUID = myFile.read(); //read each char and store to toUID
      uidContent += toUID; //store char to form a String
    }
    Serial1.print(uidContent);
    myFile.close();
  }
}
```

And it will be read by the NodeMCU then sent to another NodeMCU and stored in the SD of another Mega wirelessly using this code.

```cpp
while (1) {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    uid = Serial.readString();
    break;
  }
}
data = uid.c_str();
port.beginPacket("192.168.4.255", 2390);
port.write(data);
port.endPacket();
```

Now, is it possible to send a wav/mp3 file using this process or is there any other way?

Comment: What is the type of `uidContent`, `String`? If so, then `String` is not suitable for transmitting bytes. Also your current code will not work with big files, as it requires to load all file content to SRAM (8KB on MEGA) before sending it.

Comment: uidContent is String

Comment: do have any examples?

Comment: For the Arduino part, a quick google search for "arduino read sd file by chunk" gave me this https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=357548.0 which has an example of reading and writing a file one byte at a time. Not really performant, but it has no memory problem.

Comment: For the other side (NodeMCU), I can't comment as I don't use NodeMCU. It is likely one problem you may have is to detect when the file is finished receiving.

Comment: I am now able to send the content of the wav files from Mega to NodeMcu through its serial ports, but when i would recieve it on my other nodeMcu part, some parts of the WAV header is not being sent.

Here is a sample of the content of the original wav file:
RIFF¤L  WAVEfmt      À]  À]    data€L  €€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€

While this is what Im recieving on the other node mcu:
RIFFäN€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€

It seems to skip some of the 44byte header of the wav so I wont be able to play it on the other Mega.